# CodeIgniter 3, PHP 8 and jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Morning
Do AJAX requests in PHP 8 work normally with CodeIgniter 3?

I installed an application under CodeIgniter 3 which works perfectly since a long time under PHP 7.4. I want to install the same application in another machine running PHP 8.1.2. And there the AJAX requests no longer pass.

Comment: you'r use ajax on client side or server side?

Answer (score 0):

Try with headers

```
     $.ajax({
        url: "your url",
        headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
    });
```

Comment: With the headers it does not work either.